# How to update page title and meta data in vuejs2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am a beginner in vuejs and I try to update the page title and meta content when the route changes with the help of the following tutorial.

[updating the page title and meta content](https://alligator.io/vuejs/vue-router-modify-head/#changing-the-title--meta-tags)

But when I add the meta content into the routing file it doesn't add in the header tag.

```
routes:[
        {
            path:'/',
            component:Message,
            meta:{
                title:'testing',
            }
        }]
```

I am using vue 2.5.17 version.